# nested_form and has_many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many

I have two models called Consumer and Complaint as follows:

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :consumer
end


class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :complaints

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :complaints
end
```

Using nested_form I can register a Consumer and a Complaint at the same time, but I perform a search before to verify wheter a consumer is already registered.

If it's true, the form loads data from Consumer and loads data from all Complaints previous registered for this Consumer.

I want to load data only from Consumer and have blank fields for just one Complaint, and when submitting the form, update the Consumer, if needed, and save the new Complaint (as though the association was has_one).

I'm not fluent in English so I apologize for any mistake.